# Cannot connect to mongoDB with Nodejs using Docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I'm stucking with docker-compose to create 2 image which one is nodejs app and other is mongodb.

**My OS information**

```
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3+
OS: Raspbian buster
```

**This is my folder tree:**

```
__docker // contain mongodb data
|__docker_mongo // mongo image
|__docker_node // nodejs iamge
|__docker-compose.yml
```

Node app docker is fine without connecting to mongo.

**Database node config:**

```
const url = 'mongodb://172.20.0.3:56086/nodejs';
const url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs';
```

I've tried 2 case above but none of them success.

**MongoDB Dockerfile**

```
FROM cretzel/rpi-mongodb
WORKDIR /usr/src/mongdb
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
VOLUME ./database /data/db
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

**entrypoit.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
service mongod start
exec "$@"
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build: ./docker_node/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: npm start
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    build: ./docker_mongodb/
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

when i run `docker-compose up`, after had built image, this is log:

```
mongo_1  | Starting database: mongodb failed!
mongo_1  | db level locking enabled: 1
mongo_1  | mongod --help for help and startup options
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 
mongo_1  | warning: some regex utf8 things will not work.  pcre build doesn't have --enable-unicode-properties
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=07c67d97d0e9
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.1.1-pre-) of MongoDB.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] db version v2.1.1-pre-, pdfile version 4.5
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] git version: 47fbbdceb21fc2b791d22db7f01792500647daa9
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] build info: Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #102 PREEMPT Sat Sep 1 01:00:50 BST 2012 armv6l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:05 [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:08 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:06:08 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
web_1    | 
web_1    | > init@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
web_1    | > node ./bin/www
web_1    | 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 17:07:08 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:20 virt:83 mapped:0
web_1    | mongodb://172.20.0.3:56086/nodejs
web_1    | Error:  Unable to connect to database 
web_1    | MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
web_1    |     at mongoose.connect.then.err (/usr/src/app/src/untils/database.js:32:24)
```

It seems `service mongod start` cause this problem but i don't know how to solve it. :(

Please help.

---------------- UPDATE --------------------------------------------

When database configuration is `const url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs'`, the log file:

```
mongo_1  | Starting database: mongodb failed!
mongo_1  | db level locking enabled: 1
mongo_1  | mongod --help for help and startup options
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 
mongo_1  | warning: some regex utf8 things will not work.  pcre build doesn't have --enable-unicode-properties
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=07c67d97d0e9
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (2.1.1-pre-) of MongoDB.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] db version v2.1.1-pre-, pdfile version 4.5
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] git version: 47fbbdceb21fc2b791d22db7f01792500647daa9
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] build info: Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #102 PREEMPT Sat Sep 1 01:00:50 BST 2012 armv6l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:01:17 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
web_1    | 
web_1    | > init@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
web_1    | > node ./bin/www
web_1    | 
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:09 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35650 #1 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:09 [conn1] end connection 172.20.0.3:35650 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:09 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35652 #2 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:09 [conn2] end connection 172.20.0.3:35652 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35654 #3 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:10 [conn3] end connection 172.20.0.3:35654 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35656 #4 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:10 [conn4] end connection 172.20.0.3:35656 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:11 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35658 #5 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:11 [conn5] end connection 172.20.0.3:35658 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:11 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35660 #6 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:11 [conn6] end connection 172.20.0.3:35660 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:12 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35662 #7 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:12 [conn7] end connection 172.20.0.3:35662 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:12 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35664 #8 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:12 [conn8] end connection 172.20.0.3:35664 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35666 #9 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:13 [conn9] end connection 172.20.0.3:35666 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:13 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35668 #10 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:13 [conn10] end connection 172.20.0.3:35668 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:14 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35670 #11 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:14 [conn11] end connection 172.20.0.3:35670 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:14 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35672 #12 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:14 [conn12] end connection 172.20.0.3:35672 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:15 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35674 #13 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:15 [conn13] end connection 172.20.0.3:35674 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:15 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35676 #14 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:15 [conn14] end connection 172.20.0.3:35676 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:16 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35678 #15 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:16 [conn15] end connection 172.20.0.3:35678 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:16 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35680 #16 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:16 [conn16] end connection 172.20.0.3:35680 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:17 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:19 virt:84 mapped:0
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35682 #17 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:17 [conn17] end connection 172.20.0.3:35682 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:18 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35684 #18 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:18 [conn18] end connection 172.20.0.3:35684 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:18 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35686 #19 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:18 [conn19] end connection 172.20.0.3:35686 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:19 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35688 #20 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:19 [conn20] end connection 172.20.0.3:35688 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:19 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35690 #21 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:19 [conn21] end connection 172.20.0.3:35690 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:20 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35692 #22 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:20 [conn22] end connection 172.20.0.3:35692 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:20 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35694 #23 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:20 [conn23] end connection 172.20.0.3:35694 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:21 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35696 #24 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:21 [conn24] end connection 172.20.0.3:35696 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:21 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35698 #25 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:21 [conn25] end connection 172.20.0.3:35698 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:22 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35700 #26 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:22 [conn26] end connection 172.20.0.3:35700 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:22 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35702 #27 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:22 [conn27] end connection 172.20.0.3:35702 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:23 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35704 #28 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:23 [conn28] end connection 172.20.0.3:35704 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:23 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35706 #29 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:23 [conn29] end connection 172.20.0.3:35706 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:24 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35708 #30 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:24 [conn30] end connection 172.20.0.3:35708 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:24 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35710 #31 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:24 [conn31] end connection 172.20.0.3:35710 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:25 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35712 #32 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:25 [conn32] end connection 172.20.0.3:35712 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:25 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35714 #33 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:25 [conn33] end connection 172.20.0.3:35714 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:26 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35716 #34 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:26 [conn34] end connection 172.20.0.3:35716 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:26 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35718 #35 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:26 [conn35] end connection 172.20.0.3:35718 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:27 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35720 #36 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:27 [conn36] end connection 172.20.0.3:35720 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:27 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35722 #37 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:27 [conn37] end connection 172.20.0.3:35722 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:28 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35724 #38 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:28 [conn38] end connection 172.20.0.3:35724 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:28 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35726 #39 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:28 [conn39] end connection 172.20.0.3:35726 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:29 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35728 #40 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:29 [conn40] end connection 172.20.0.3:35728 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:29 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35730 #41 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:29 [conn41] end connection 172.20.0.3:35730 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:30 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35732 #42 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:30 [conn42] end connection 172.20.0.3:35732 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:30 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35734 #43 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:30 [conn43] end connection 172.20.0.3:35734 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:31 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35736 #44 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:31 [conn44] end connection 172.20.0.3:35736 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:31 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35738 #45 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:31 [conn45] end connection 172.20.0.3:35738 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:32 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35740 #46 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:32 [conn46] end connection 172.20.0.3:35740 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:32 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35742 #47 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:32 [conn47] end connection 172.20.0.3:35742 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:33 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35744 #48 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:33 [conn48] end connection 172.20.0.3:35744 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:33 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35746 #49 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:33 [conn49] end connection 172.20.0.3:35746 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:34 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35748 #50 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:34 [conn50] end connection 172.20.0.3:35748 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:34 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35750 #51 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:34 [conn51] end connection 172.20.0.3:35750 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:35 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35752 #52 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:35 [conn52] end connection 172.20.0.3:35752 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:35 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35754 #53 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:35 [conn53] end connection 172.20.0.3:35754 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:36 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35756 #54 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:36 [conn54] end connection 172.20.0.3:35756 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:36 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35758 #55 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:36 [conn55] end connection 172.20.0.3:35758 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:37 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35760 #56 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:37 [conn56] end connection 172.20.0.3:35760 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:37 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35762 #57 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:37 [conn57] end connection 172.20.0.3:35762 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:38 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35764 #58 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:38 [conn58] end connection 172.20.0.3:35764 (0 connections now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:39 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:35766 #59 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | Mon Nov 11 18:02:39 [conn59] end connection 172.20.0.3:35766 (0 connections now open)
web_1    | mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs
web_1    | Error:  Unable to connect to database 
web_1    | MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
web_1    |     at mongoose.connect.then.err (/usr/src/app/src/untils/database.js:32:24)
```

Comment: Hi! What happens when you try and connect to `mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs` instead of `mongodb://172.20.0.3:56086/nodejs`?

Comment: remove `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]` from your mongo DB dockerfile, `CMD` enough. also your connection string should be `const url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs';` and seems like DB is not running at all, try to use offical mongo docker image. https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: @Edrian It has log same like ```mongodb://172.20.0.3:56086/nodejs``` but it also shows that it opened connection on ip: ```172.20.0.3``` with port from ```35768``` to ```35884```. You can see full log on post (which i eddited).

Comment: @Adiii, I've remove ENTRYPOINT and it didn't show ```Starting database: mongodb failed!``` anymore, i think mongo service started.  But if I change my database configuration to ```const url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/nodejs``` it shows like above (update part on my post). 
And I've tried to create image with ```mongo``` image on ```hub.docker.com``` but it shows that mongo image doesn't fit with linux armv7 architechture

Comment: now the error make sense, you can check https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6692

Comment: Finally, I solved problem and success in connect to mongodb server. Thank to @Adiii for your help. The log prints repeatedly because a optional parameter ```useUnifiedTopology: true``` (i don't know why but if i add this param to option, it causes to above result) of ```mongooes.connect()``` which try to find a port to connect. Then I added command ```mongod --bind_ip_all```, it showed that this command is only for mongo 2.6 while mine is 2.1. After hours finding, i found a image which suitable for my project. It's ```andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3
``` which installed mongo 3.x

Comment: Thats great you make it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, change `cretzel/rpi-mongodb` to `andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3`