# cannot connect to MongoDB with Docker-compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create 2 containers with Docker-compose which one contain Mongo serive and another contain web service written by NodeJS. 
This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    build: ./docker_mongo/
    volumes: 
      - ./database:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  node_app:
    build: ./docker_node/
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "16427:16427"
    command: npm start
    environment:
      - OS:PI
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - mqtt
```

When I ran `docker-compose`, mongo service display this message:

```
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.699+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=90cbb91eebd0
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.14
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1622021384533dade8b3c89ed3ecd80e1142c132
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Support for MMAPV1 storage engine has been deprecated and will be
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          removed in version 4.2. Please plan to migrate to the wiredTiger
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          storage engine.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/deprecated-mmapv1
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.708+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.727+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.728+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.730+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]  WARNING: This file system is not supported. For further information see:
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.730+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]                  http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/unsupported-filesystems
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.730+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]          Please notify MongoDB, Inc. if an unlisted filesystem generated this warning.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.970+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:39.971+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]  WARNING: This file system is not supported. For further information see:
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]                  http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/unsupported-filesystems
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]          Please notify MongoDB, Inc. if an unlisted filesystem generated this warning.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.003+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.308+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongo_1      | 2020-01-05T07:36:40.312+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

This shows that mongo service is ready on port `27017`, but NodeJs server still could not to database:

```
node_app_1   | Error:  Unable to connect to database
node_app_1   | MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
node_app_1   |     at /node_app/app.js:84:20
```

With NodeJs server, mongoDb connect to url `mongodb://mongo:27017/docker` with `mongo` is the name of docker-compose service. I also tried with `localhost` but it didn't work.

I've tried this on a raspberry Pi, and it worked (just change `mongo` image).
[Mongo Image on Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798837/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-with-nodejs-using-docker-compose?noredirect=1#comment103892791_58798837)
Can someone help?

Comment: hope this will help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962012/how-to-connect-nodejs-docker-container-to-mongodb/43962099
https://ciphertrick.com/dockerize-nodejs-service-with-mongodb-docker-compose/

Comment: @Dipakchavda thanks for rep, unfortunately, those solution are so unclear for me.

Comment: @simpsons3, what is the hostname of the mongo that you pass to your nodejs application ?

Comment: `WARNING: This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.`  In this context "remote" is anything at all outside the container.  You need to adjust your configuration as shown (or use the Docker Hub `mongo` image).

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect two containers, first, you have to understand docker networking. You are getting error probably because containers are isolated. There are multiple ways you can connect docker containers using different networking mode like:

- Host-only network
- Bridge networking

Read more here https://docs.docker.com/network/

You can configure host-only network as below:
Include  `network_mode: host` for each service.

```
  version: '3'
    services:
      mongo:
        build: ./docker_mongo/
        network_mode: host
        volumes: 
          - ./database:/data/db
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
      node_app:
        build: ./docker_node/
        network_mode: host
        ports:
          - "3001:3001"
          - "16427:16427"
        command: npm start
        environment:
          - OS:PI
        depends_on:
          - mongo
          - mqtt
```

Comment: This might be useful as well: https://www.edureka.co/blog/docker-networking/

Comment: sorry for lately reply. I just have tried your solution, but it still didn't work, it showed a warning `WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.`.

Comment: are you not able to connect to mongo or just getting the warning?

Comment: I'm not able to connect to mongo and still getting the warning.

Comment: It showed that mongo take to long to connect, so i think problem come from mongoDB configuration in NodeJS but i don't know how to config it.